# How to show vertical text in clj-pdf?

Tags: clojure, clj-pdf

I tried by adding "\n" after every letter, doesn't look good though.
I need something like this in cell. Some how the I and L don't align with the rest adding spaces messes up everything.

```
V
E
R
T
I
C
A
L
```

Comment: Are you using a monospaced font?

Comment: Its the default font.